# Transformation of random variables and second-order stochastic dominance

Tags: risk, finance-mathematics, mathematics

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables where $X$ SOSD* $Y$. Let $g(\bullet)$ be a monotonic function and $X'=g(X)$ and $Y'=g(Y)$. Under what conditions of $g$ is

$X'$ SOSD $Y'$?

I know if $g$ is linear, SOSD property is reserved. Is there any suff and nec conditions of $g$ that assures SOSD property ?

---

**second-order stochastic dominance.*

Comment: Hi and welcome. Would you like to add a definition of SOSD to the question. I found it on wikipedia but this would make the question more self-contained.

Comment: Echo to Richard, why not explicit define SOSD in mathematical sense?